# matplotlib & seaborn - How to know the function/equation of a exponential distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DataFrame(`dtest`) and I plotted it into boxplot.

```
  NoUsager Periods Sens Date     Weekday DureeService/second
0  19      Matin    + 2015-07-10  Ven     578.0 
1  19      Soir     - 2015-07-10  Ven     8.0 
2  19      Matin    + 2015-09-10 Jeu      1226.0 
3  19      Soir     - 2015-09-10 Jeu      9.0 
4  19      Matin    + 2015-12-10 Jeu      1067.0 
5  19      Soir     - 2015-12-10 Jeu      7.0 
6  19      Matin    + 2015-10-13 Mar      131.0 
7  19      Soir     - 2015-10-13 Mar      10.0 
8  19      Matin    + 2015-10-14 Mer      981.0 
9  19      Soir     - 2015-10-14 Mer      9.0 
10 19      Matin    + 2015-02-12 Jeu      1007.0 
11 19      Soir     - 2015-02-12 Jeu      421.0 
12 19      Matin    + 2016-01-20 Mer      277.0 
13 19      Soir     - 2016-01-20 Mer      99.0 
14 19      Matin    + 2016-01-21 Jeu      385.0 

plt.figure()
list1 = dtest['DureeService/second']
sns.distplot(list1,bins=60)
```

[image]

And I got this graph as result. My graph was generated by existing dataframe so there were no equation or other key numbers. Is there a way to know exactly what's the equation of distribution of this histogram plot?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I'd recommend reading the [kernel density tutorial](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/distributions.html#kernel-density-estimaton).

Comment: I did and I found that normally all the key factors were already given.